# Session for each tab - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

In a Google Chrome Extension, is there a way to have different "sessions" for each tab?

For exemple, Adblock does that: it shows the number of blocked ads for the current page, and this number changes for each tab (and if you have 2 windows open, a different number for each window...)

For exemple, if I use the Chrome demo to change the icon on click :

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "A browser action which changes its icon when clicked",
 "description": "Change browser action color when its icon is clicked",
 "version": "1.2",
 "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
 "browser_action": {
     "name": "Click to change the icon's color"
 },
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
var min = 1;
var max = 5;
var current = min;

function updateIcon() {
 chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon" + current + ".png"});
 current++;

 if (current > max)
   current = min;
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
updateIcon();
```

Is there a way to add some code to have a different "scope" on each tab? For exemple, if I click 3 times on the first tab, it would show icon3, and if I open a new tab, it would show icon1 for this tab (but still icon3 for the first tab)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrome.browserAction` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) takes tabs into account by providing, and taking, `tabId` as a parameter.

For example, here's the expected signature of an `onClicked` listener:

> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>
> ```
> function( tabs.Tab tab) {...};
> ```
>
> [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)   `tab`

So, in your `updateIcon` function, you can get the ID of the tab:

```
function updateIcon(tab) {
  // Can use tab.id here
  /* ... */
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path:"icon" + current + ".png",
    tabId: tab.id // Limit change to tab
  });
}
```

**Of course, this means you have to store your data per-tab.** Simplest way is to make `current` an Object (or Array, but it'll be sparse) with `tabId`s acting like keys.

```
var min = 1;
var max = 5;
var current = {};

function updateIcon(tab) {
  if (!current[tab.id]) { // Not yet defined
    current[tab.id] = min;
  }

  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: "icon" + current[tab.id] + ".png",
    tabId: tab.id
  });

  if (current[tab.id] === max) {
    current[tab.id] = min;
  } else {
    current[tab.id]++;
  }
}
```

If you're wary of the tab data growing over time, you can listen to `chrome.tabs.onRemoved` to clear the data out.

You may also want to pay attention to `chrome.tabs.onReplaced` (which replaces the content within a tab, changing the ID).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was starting to look at pageAction instead of browserAction but I was stuck on it... your solution is way easier though

Comment: In Google's [current paradigm](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ) Page Actions are strictly inferior versions of Browser Actions, since they no longer can be shown only on relevant pages. They even tell _"Please consider using a browser action instead, so that users can always interact with your extension"_ right in the documentation.